# Excel formula that looks for a substring and counts unique values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, count, substring, unique

I am looking for an Excel formula that looks for a substring and counts unique values.

Assume column B contains:

Kansas_Pink_Fish

Kansas_Pink_Fish

Kansas_Pink_Fish

Kansas_Pink_Bird

Kansas_Pink_Turtle

Missouri_Red_Bird

Missouri_Red_Bird

Missouri_Pink_Bird

Missouri_Pink_Bird

Ohio_Pink_Fish

Ohio_Green_Fish

Ohio_Green_Turtle

Ohio_Green_Turtle

Looking for the number of "*Pink*" items.
*Pink* would be in the formula, not necessarily a reference to a cell.

The answer would be 4.

Kansas_Pink_Fish
Kansas_Pink_Bird
Kansas_Pink_Turtle
Missouri_Pink_Bird

I am not looking for the list, I am looking for the count.

I have tried a couple of things but I either get an error, #value, or the number 100 (which I think may be the upper limit of one of the functions I was trying to use).

The actual list is Over 38K rows.
The answer is just over 1K when doing it by hand:

- Filter > contains *Pink*
- Copy results to another tab
- Sort
- Remove duplicates
- Count

---

```
=COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(B:B,ISNUMBER(SEARCH("_Pink_",B:B)))))
```

---

```
=COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(B:B,ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*_Pink_*",B:B)))))
```

I was expecting 1,094

Comment: It's 5: you forgot `Ohio_Pink_Fish`.

Answer (score 1):

```
=SUM(--ISTEXT(UNIQUE(TOCOL(IFS(ISNUMBER(FIND("_Pink_",A:A)),A:A),2))))
```

This first checks column A for the presence of the string `_Pink_` (case sensitive; in case you want it to be case insensitive replace FIND for SEARCH). This is wrapped in `IFS`. If it is present it returns the value of column A, else it returns an error.

This array of values and errors is wrapped in `TOCOL` with argument `2` to ignore error values.

This returns an array of all values containing `_Pink_`. Wrapping it in `UNIQUE` leaves only the distinct uniques from the array.
We need to count the number of unique values, but since we also have the ability that no matches are found, for which `UNIQUE` returns one line containing an error. If we then would use `ROWS` or `COUNTA` it'd return 1 instead of 0, so we wrap it in `ISTEXT` which results in TRUE for each non-error line, or in case of the error it returns `FALSE`.

Add `--` in front of the value(s) converts TRUE to 1 or FALSE to 0. If we now `SUM` it we have the expected outcome.

Edit:
Or shorter using `1-ISERR` as suggested by Mayukh:

```
=SUM(1-ISERR(UNIQUE(FILTER(A:A,1-ISERR(FIND("_Pink_",A:A))))))
```

Here `1-ISERR` can be seen as `NOT(ISERR` and can be used instead of `ISNUMBER` and `--ISTEXT`

Comment: Another alternative version & shorter btw: `=SUM(1-ISERR(UNIQUE(FILTER(A:A,1-ISERR(FIND("_Pink_",A:A))))))` using `ISERR()` saves `9` bytes.