# Count of Unique Values based on who it's assigned to?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table of landowners, agents assigned to them, and the status of project.
[image]

In column F, I want a unique count of how many unique landowners are assigned to each agent (column E) based on the value "Outreach" in column C.

The picture is expected output based on this formula, but it's not working when I type in the formula?

```
=COUNTA(UNIQUE(A:A,COUNTIFS(B:B=E2,C:C="Outreach")))
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly your goal, you want to group the range by two fields.

`=COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A10,(B2:B10="Mike")*(C2:C10="Outreach"))))`

You can combine this with `UNIQUE(B2:B10)` to generate a list of agents.

This is a very temporary solution as of this time. The beta channel in Excel just released a new function `GROUPBY()`. Once it goes to main channel, you would be able to do what you want just by using it.

see https://insider.microsoft365.com/en-us/blog/new-aggregation-functions-in-excel-groupby-and-pivotby

Comment: In case there is no match UNIQUE returns an error and COUNTA returns 1. You could work around this using `SUM(N(ISTEXT(UNIQUE..` (more explained here https://stackoverflow.com/a/77933561/12634230)

Comment: Or `IFERROR(ROWS(UNIQUE(...)),)` like VBasics posted

Comment: Assuming that data allows for zero counts, yes. I would recommend using IFERROR() where possible. However, this possibility was not stated in the original question, so falls outside the scope of task.

Answer (score 3):

### Count Unique Filtered By Two Columns

```
=IFERROR(ROWS(UNIQUE(FILTER(A$2:A$11,(B$2:B$11=E2)*(C$2:C$11="Outreach")))),)
```

- If you want to start writing these formulas on your own, stop using entire column references.
- Observe how the formula was built step by step.

[image]

Comment: @P.b I did, but do you see my screenshot? Why does it work anyway? I know `CountA` doesn't. Any ideas? It looks like `IFERROR` decided that if there are two consecutive (or cumulative) (`#CALC!`) errors, it will ignore the rest of the formula (`ROWS`). Actually any errors, it still works after using e.g. `NA()` with the 3rd `FILTER` argument.

Comment: I see, ROWS returns an error indeed, so will result in 0, so what you did is correct. I thought ROWS would return 1 like COUNTA, but it doesn't.

Comment: @P.b But it's still not clear (sheer luck) i.e. if I go step by step in the cells, it will return 1. What's happening?

Comment: In that case it's the count of the range, otherwise an array

Comment: @VBasic2008 Sir , P.b Sir Op posted same question in reddit as well but got solved it here first: **[Take A Look](https://www.reddit.com/r/excel/comments/1ai33fh/count_unique_of_one_column_based_on_conditions_in/)**

Comment: Without using `ROWS()` & `IFERROR()` perhaps: `=SUM(1-ISERR(UNIQUE(FILTER(A$2:A$10,(E2=B$2:B$10)*(C$2:C$10="Outreach")))))`