# COUNT UNIQUE FILTER formula not calculating correctly?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have three columns shown in a file:

Column B is a landowner

Column M is the agent who was assigned the landowner

Column N is the status of the assignment

I want to do a count formula to see how many unique landowners the agent has "signed". When I filter my sheet called "Master", I can see that only 1 agent has signed:

[image]

So when I go to my formula, it still shows a 0 for Kevin, but there should be a 1:

[image]

I have the -1 at the end of the formula to omit the header row in the count. When I take that off, everyone gets a 1 in the formula when that isn't accurate.

Formula:

```
=COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(Master!$B:$B,(Master!$M:$M=Metrics!$A17)* 
(Master!$N:$N="Signed"))))-1
```

Comment: Use `SUM()` with an error control instead of using `COUNTA()` --> `SUM(--(UNIQUE(FILTER(Master!$B:$B,(Master!$M:$M=Metrics!$A17)* 
(Master!$N:$N="Signed")))<>""))`

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya Hey so I think I figured it out in a way easier way. Couldn't I just do `=UNIQUE(COUNTIFS(Master!M:M,A15,Master!N:N,"Signed"))`?

Comment: Does it work? Are you sure `COUNTIFS()` work with spilled arrays?

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya AH ok I see that the countifs with unique still doesn't give me a unique count of what's in column B.

Comment: Also I have suggested here: **[Check](https://www.reddit.com/r/excel/comments/1ai33fh/count_unique_of_one_column_based_on_conditions_in/)** Using `SUM()` is far better than using `COUNTA()` or `ROWS()` for such scenarios. Hope it makes sense. Discussed here in comments: **[Refer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77933544/8162520)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `COUNTA()` function use `SUM()` with an error check as well. That said, you can amend the formulas as follows:

- Filter the data by conditions:

---

```
=FILTER(Master!$B:$B,(Master!$M:$M=Metrics!$A17)*(Master!$N:$N="Signed"))
```

---

- Get Unique Values

---

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(Master!$B:$B,(Master!$M:$M=Metrics!$A17)*(Master!$N:$N="Signed")))
```

---

- Get the counts to check whether there is no blanks assumes there are no spaces here:

---

```
=SUM(--(UNIQUE(FILTER(Master!$B:$B,(Master!$M:$M=Metrics!$A17)*(Master!$N:$N="Signed")))<>""))
```

---